# There is no data transfer in modifier

Tags: modifiers

I am currently using Blender 2.70
And I've noticed that there is the "data transfer" tab missing in my blender.
[image: Under modify tab, shouldn't there be "Data tranfser"?]
If not, where else can I find that?

Comment: You don't want to use the 2.79?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a feature request for an obsolete Blender version from March, 2014.

Comment: There won't be any DataTransfer modifier in Blender 2.70, it is present [in 2.74](https://en.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.74/Modeling#Mesh_Data_Transfer) and above

Comment: @MrZak Care to make that an answer? This seems like a perfectly valid question to me, and that seems like a perfectly valid answer.

Comment: @gandalf3 no thanks, everyone who wants is welcome to add instead

Answer (score 1):

As Mr. Zak said in the comments, the Data Transfer modifier was not added until Blender 2.74. You can upgrade by downloading the application from the **[Blender website](https://www.blender.org/download/)**.